# How can I split string fastly in Java?

Tags: java, split

I have to divide my message regularly with "@". I must separate sections with the first @ sign but i have some speed problems.
I can explain it more easily with code :

```
String mymessage = "java@hel@@lo @world!@@@";
String[] mysplit = fastlySeparateFunc(mymessage);
System.out.println(mysplit[0]);
System.out.println(mysplit[1]);

/*
and output must be like this :
java
hel@@lo @world!@@@
*/
```

How can i write it? (fastlySeparateFunc)

Comment: How are you splitting it "slowly"? Doesn't `mymessage.split("@", 2)` do what you want?

Comment: [`string.split(r, limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)

Comment: Use the Java standard library as suggested. These methods ship with the language and are heavily optimized for maximum performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the fastest you can do this is to use `String.indexOf`:

```
int pos = mymessage.indexOf('@');
String[] mysplit = {mymessage.substring(0, pos), mymessage.substring(pos+1)};
```

But I doubt it will be appreciably faster than:

```
String[] mysplit = mymessage.split("@", 2);
```

I suspect it might be *slightly* faster to use `indexOf`, because you're not having to use the full regex machinery. But I think the difference would be marginal.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Well, it *takes* a `String`, but parses the string as a regex... :-) (`String` could use a `split(char)` and/or `splitRaw(String)` or similar...)

Comment: I just realized that, looking at the docs. Why no overload taking a `Pattern` I wonder....

Comment: "Andy Turner" Thank you so much.
Your codes are faster than the traditional code.

Comment: @Nickname out of interest, how much faster?

Comment: 54.95% faster in this situation but as the length of the message increases, your codes stability decreases and their performances are equalized(if message length around 1000.).

Comment: Edit : (If the message length is approximately 3000 and the @ sign is repeated continuously)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the String into StringTokenizer object and split it at the delimiter'@'

```
StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(mymessage,'@');
```

Comment: Why make a string builder from a string, and then immediately build the string again? That's exactly the same as just using the string, except for creating at least 1, almost certainly 2, unnecessary objects.

Comment: My mistake, I intended to use StringTokenizer and not StringBuilder.
Edited for usage now

Comment: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead." ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/StringTokenizer.html))

Comment: I agree with you, however the implementation of stringTokenizer is easy.
.split() is faster.